# How to include a portrait layout in a landscape layout?

Tags: android, layout, landscape

I have designed the perfect portrait layout.  I'd like to include is as a part of the landscape version (see attachment).

[image: Layout for Landscape version]

There is no extra functionality, so I don't see a need to go to trouble of using Fragments.

Of course, one cannot include the portrait version of a layout in the landscape version.  The following code produces the obvious error of "layouts should not include itself":

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/my_perfect_layout"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/demo"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to force a layout directory so that I don't get this include infinite loop?  Or is there another way altogether?  I'd really like to avoid changing any java code at this point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice:

- Put your content layout into a orientation-less layout file. (this is the reusable part)
- Create a frame layout file for all orientations you want to use and include the content layout. (this is the part where you put layout-specific parts, e.g. include more stuff in landscape)

Comment: Creating a third file as you suggested does the trick.  Thanks for the help!